# Selenium IDE Installation on Firefox

Tags: selenium

The version of Mozilla firefox that is on my machine is the latest one 55.03. I went to seleniumhq.org and here is the relevant content I observed

Selenium IDE

Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin which records and plays back user interactions with the browser. Use this to either create simple scripts or assist in exploratory testing. It can also export Remote Control or WebDriver scripts, though they tend to be somewhat brittle and should be overhauled into some sort of Page Object-y structure for any kind of resiliency.

Download latest released version from addons.mozilla.org or view the Release Notes and then install some plugins.

Download previous versions here.

I clicked on "addons.mozilla.org" to have the latest version of Selenium IDE add-in installed.

But, I saw the button "Add to Firefox" disabled. I also saw a message saying that this version of the add-in is not compatible with firefox that you have on your machine.

I followed the same steps on a newer version of the browser(by uninstalling the older version of the browser and installed the newer version) The problem is the same again

What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Install Selenium IDE for Firefox then follow the step

**After Firefox has restarted, launch Selenium IDE using either of two ways:
By pressing Ctrl+Alt+S**

**or**

**By clicking on the Firefox menu button> Developer>Selenium IDE**

[image]

**Selenium IDE should launch as shown below**

Hope Your problem will be solved